# pandas group by function applied to a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the Groupby documentation, I only see examples of grouping by functions applied to the index of axis 0 or to the labels of the columns. I see no examples discussing how to group by a label derived from applying a function to a column. I would think this would be done using `apply`. Is the example below the best way to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d','e'], 20), 
               'num1': np.random.randint(low = 30, high=100, size=20),
               'num2': np.random.randint(low = -3, high=9, size=20)})

df.head()

  name  num1 num2
0   d   34  7
1   b   49  6
2   a   51  -1
3   d   79  8
4   e   72  5

def num1_greater_than_60(number_num1):
    if number_num1 >= 60:
        return 'greater'
    else:
        return 'less'

df.groupby(df['num1'].apply(num1_greater_than_60))
```

Answer (score 5):

from DataFrame.groupby() docs:

```
by : mapping, function, str, or iterable
    Used to determine the groups for the groupby.
    If ``by`` is a function, it's called on each value of the object's
    index. If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES
    will be used to determine the groups (the Series' values are first
    aligned; see ``.align()`` method). If an ndarray is passed, the
    values are used as-is determine the groups. A str or list of strs
    may be passed to group by the columns in ``self``
```

so we can do it this way:

```
In [35]: df.set_index('num1').groupby(num1_greater_than_60)[['name']].count()
Out[35]:
         name
greater    15
less        5
```

Comment: thank you @MaxU I was trying to do it without setting the column as an index because they might not be unique. Or does that not matter?

Comment: @dleal, can you post your desired data set?

Comment: I was trying to be as general as possible. Maybe I should change the example to make it more clear that the column I try to groupby has repeated values?

Comment: @dleal, the uniqueness of index doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do without apply here

```
df.groupby(df.num1.gt(60))

df.num1.gt(60)
Out[774]: 
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False
9      True
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
14    False
15     True
16    False
17    False
18     True
19    False
Name: num1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: this is true, but I wanted to just exemplify an easy function. In general the function might not be one of the available methods

Comment: I think an example using a custom function rather than the built-in `gt` one would be more helpful, and possibly more complex.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would do this by creating a derived column to then groupby - I find this easier to keep track of and can always delete this or select only columns needed at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d','e'], 20), 
               'num1': np.random.randint(low = 30, high=100, size=20),
               'num2': np.random.randint(low = -3, high=9, size=20)})

df['num1_greater_than_60'] = df['num1'].gt(60).replace(
    to_replace=[True, False], 
    value=['greater', 'less'])

df.groupby('num1_greater_than_60').dosomething()
```

Comment: thank you @Ken_Syme this is what i usually do as well, but i wondered if there was something aside from creating an artificial column